# React-router Link changes URL but doesn't rerender

Tags: reactjs, react-router, mobx, mobx-react

I'm using MobX to render some orders with React and React-router. When I'm using Link the URL changes, but the view doesn't get rendered. When I refresh the page, the view is as it should be. I searched for a while and found [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md) that MobX observer blocks rerendering because it uses shouldComponentUpdate. I tried using the location method, because that prop changes and should trigger a re-render, but that doesn't seem to help.

I also tried to use withRouter, but I didn't manage to implement that as a decorator.

**Update**
In [this thread](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/issues/210) it's said that the decorators are breaking react-router? Using withRouter fixes it for them, but still I do not know how I should implement this into my code...

**index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider {...stores}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App location={location} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Switch, Route, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Order} from './components';
import {AllOrders} from './containers';
import {inject, observer} from 'mobx-react';
import {isEmpty} from 'lodash';

const App = ({orders, location}) => {
  console.log(location);
  return(
    <Switch>
      {
        !isEmpty(orders) && <Route exact path="/orders" render={(props) => (<AllOrders {...props} orders={orders} />)} />
      }
      {
        !isEmpty(orders) && <Route path="/orders/:id" render={(props) => (<Order {...props} orders={orders} />)} />
      }
    </Switch>
  )
}

export default inject(
  ({orderStore}) => ({
    orders: orderStore.orders
  })
)(
  observer(App)
);
```

**AllOrders.js**

```
class AllOrders extends Component{

  render(){
    const {orders} = this.props;
    return(
      <div>
        {
          !isEmpty(orders) &&
          orders.map((props, key) => {
            return(
              <Link to={`/orders/${props.id}`} key={key}>{props.id}<br /></Link>
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default AllOrders;
```

Comment: Does your App rerenders when you change route?

Comment: No it does not, the log of location doesn't get triggered. I also added the component which contains the Links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside my BrowserRouter I added the component App, instead it should've been a Route which is passed the component App. This made the routing work again. The solution was changing my index.js to

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider {...stores}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route component={App} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```